# Cambiar una propiedad de un array multidimensional

Tags: javascript, array, angular, map

Necesito modificar un array para tener unas propiedades concretas, ya que trabajando con el tree view y treeMap de primeNg necesito sincronizarlos...

El array es el siguiente:

```
 "data":
[  
    {  
        "data":{  
            "label":"Applications",
            "name":"Applications",
            "size":"200mb",
            "type":"Folder"
        },
        "children":[  
            {  
                "data":{  
                    "name":"Angular",
                    "size":"25mb",
                    "type":"Folder"
                },
                "children":[  
                    {  
                        "data":{  
                            "name":"angular.app",
                            "size":"10mb",
                            "type":"Application"
                        }
                    },
                    {  
                        "data":{  
                            "name":"cli.app",
                            "size":"10mb",
                            "type":"Application"
                        }
                    },
                    {  
                        "data":{  
                            "name":"mobile.app",
                            "size":"5mb",
                            "type":"Application"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
```

Necesito cambiar las propiedades name por el nombre de label. He conseguido los dos primeros níveles:

```
this.nodeService.getFilesystem().then(files => {

  this.files = files.map( item => {

    let children = item.children?.map(child =>({ label: child.data.name, ...child })).flat();

    delete item.children

    return {label: item.data.label, children, expandedIcon: "pi pi-folder-open", collapsedIcon: "pi pi-folder", ...item}
  });

});
```

Pero el último children no consigo realizarlo...

¿Alguna sugrencia de como modificarlo, por favor?

Gracias,

Comment: Necesitas cambiar el valor de la propiedad name, o necesitas que la propiedad en sí sea renombrada?

Comment: Tendría que ser renombrada la propiedad, ya que el tree de PrimeNG solo reconoce una estructura concreta de json o eso entiendo yo viendo la documentación. https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/tree

Comment: Podrías utilizar una función recursiva. Quiere decir, una función que se llame a si misma. Dicha función comprueba si existe el hijo "children", si no existe se "para"; si existe vuelves a llamar a la función retornando el resultado. De esta forma no importa cuantos hijos repitan la misma estructura

Comment: Lo puedes conseguir con un [*Iterador* o *Generador*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Planteo una función la cual puede modificar la propiedad del array y también según se requiera agregar claves expandedIcon y collapsedIcon tanto para cada objeto o si se prefiere solo como objetos del primer children lo cual esta comentado

> Tenes alguna dificultad adicional por la cual mi respuesta no te es de
> utilidad?

```js
const arry = [{
  "data": {
    "label": "Applications",
    "name": "Angular",

  },
  "children": [{
    "data": {
      "name": "Angular",

    },
    "children": [{
        "data": {
          "name": "angular.app",

        }
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "name": "cli.app",

        }
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "name": "mobile.app",

        }
      }
    ]

  }]
}]


const edit = (name, arr, expandedIcon, collapsedIcon) => {

  ({ ...arr[0]
  }).children[0].data.name = name;

  ({ ...arr[0]
  }).children[0].children = ({ ...arr[0]
  }).children[0].children.map((obj) =>
    ({ ...obj.data,
      name
    })
  );
  //si queremos agregar claves objexpandedIcon y collapsedIcon para cada uno
  ({ ...arr[0]
  }).children[0].children = ({ ...arr[0]
  }).children[0].children.
  map((obj) =>
    ({ ...obj,
      objexpandedIcon: expandedIcon,
      collapsedIcon: collapsedIcon
    }))
  /*
  si quisieramos agregar pero no para cada children interior
   ({...arr[0]}).children[0].children=  [
     ...[
     {...arr[0]}.children[0].children,
   {expandedIcon:expandedIcon},{collapsedIcon:collapsedIcon}
   ]
   ];
   */

}
edit('Aplicacion', arry, "pi pi-folder-open", "pi pi-folder")
console.log('arry', arry)
```

> Podemos también mediante la **desestructuración** de objetos anidados
> profundamente modificar las propiedades muy fácilmente:

```js
const arry = [
  {
    data: { label: 'Applications', name: 'Applications' },
    children: [
      {
        data: { name: 'Applications' },
        children: [
          { data: { name: 'Applications' } },
          { data: { name: 'Applications' } },
          { data: { name: 'Applications' } }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
let [{
  children: [{
    data,
    children
  }]
}] = arry;

data.name = arry[0].data.label;

children.map(obj => obj.data.name = arry[0].data.label);
console.log(arry);
```